# Append lists as columns in Pandas DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have extracted some html using BeautifulSoup, and created a function to get the useful information only. I intend to run this function for multiple keywords, and put them in a dataframe. However, I cannot get to all lists into the pandas DataFrame.

Example:

```
words = ['header', 'title', 'number']
```

The following code gets me lists all headers, titles and numbers and are all the same length.

```
def create_list(x):
    column = []
    BRKlist = BRK.find_all(x)
    for n in BRKlist:
        drop_beginning = r'<'+x+'>'
        drop_end = r'</'+x+'>'
        no_beginning = re.sub(drop_beginning, '', str(n))
        final = re.sub(drop_end, '', str(no_beginning))
        column.append(final)
    print(column)
```

This code outputs:

```
['header1', 'header2', 'header3']
['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
['number1', 'number2', 'number3']
```

I am looking for something to get 1 dataframe that gives me a DataFrame that looks like this:

| header | title | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| header1 | title1 | number1 |
| header2 | title2 | number2 |
| header3 | title3 | number3 |

Getting the lists was no problem, but when I make an empty data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({x: []})
```

and try to append the columns, I get the following error:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Is there any way to circumvent this, or any other/easier way to "append columns"?

Comment: are you planning to build a DataFrame inside `create_list` or outside? As it stands, this function doesn't return anything; just prints lists.

Comment: @enke Thanks for your answer, I indeed want to create the DataFrame inside the create_list function, so I can export it easily to CSV afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build a dataframe with only three columns, the easiest way maybe is:

```
 import pandas as pd 
 A= [['header1', 'header2', 'header3'],
 ['title1', 'title2', 'title3'],
 ['number1', 'number2', 'number3']]
df= pd.DataFrame()
df['header']= [A[0][i] for i in range(3)]
df['title']= [A[1][i] for i in range(3)]
df['number']= [A[2][0] for i in range(3)]
df
```

Comment: `df=pd.DataFrame(zip(*A), columns=words)` would be a little concise.

Comment: @enke You always has a better solution:)

Comment: Thanks, but the 3 columns are just an example. I might want more columns, in which case I only want to add an item to the list 'words'. The function should add the additional column automatically.

Comment: @enke Thanks, this is really helpful. I created a nested list and this function turns it into a DataFrame with the proper column names. However       df=pd.DataFrame(zip(*A), columns=words) only works outside the function. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @Not_a_Robot that's because `A` is built using `create_list()`, right? In general, it's more efficient to store your data in a list and build a DataFrame once (since you're working with a list anyway) instead of building a DataFrame/Series in a loop and concatenating them later on. So building `df` outside the function is the correct way imo.

Comment: @Not_a_Robot If your question is answered, please consider accepting this answer so that your question no longer remains an open issue. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now! I got the solution I was looking for.